White ring around CSS image
I am trying to create a flowing action button, but the British flag had a white ring around it, which I do not want. I want the two flags to be centered above the British flag. I wouldn't mind the british flag being as big as the white ring.


document.querySelector('.lang-dropbtn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('.lang-dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show');
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop propagation to prevent window click handler from closing the dropdown immediately
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.closest('.language-dropdown')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("lang-dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      dropdowns[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
.language-dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2000;
  /* Ensuring it is above other content */
}

.lang-dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Rounded button */
}

.lang-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  /* Adjusted for spacing */
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Padding around flags */
}

.lang-dropdown-content .lang-a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* Vertical spacing between flags */
}

.lang-dropdown-content .lang-a .lang-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Make images circular */
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  /* Center align images */
}

.language-dropdown:hover .lang-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  /* Show dropdown on hover */
}
<div class="language-dropdown">
  <button class="lang-dropbtn">
    <img class="lang-img" src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/171f64-06f6-0f4b-8e88-7b2cded67131_british_flag.png" alt="British" style="width:40px;height:auto;">
  </button>
  <div class="lang-dropdown-content">
    <!-- <a class="lang-a" href="/en"><img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/171f64-06f6-0f4b-8e88-7b2cded67131_british_flag.png" alt="British"></a> -->
    <a class="lang-a" href="/cn"><img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/e0bb117-b0a2-40b-0145-11ae625b76ca_chinese_flag.png" alt="Chinese"></a>
    <a class="lang-a" href="/ar"><img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/7c2c8b5-343-6aa2-240-dd2613be2af8_saudi_flag.png" alt="Arabic"></a>
  </div>
</div>





The placements of the flags are dependent on screen resolution. You may want to fix that as well.

This doesn't work on my end. Are you sure you have included all of the styling?

I've excluded the head and body tags

Your .lang-dropbtn has  padding value, which reveals the default background color of a button element.  You could either remove the padding value, remove the background-color, or do the both.

If the problem isn't only that 16px padding round the flag could you give us more code, showing how you are formatting the other flags. Also, are you using your browser devtools to inspect the elements to see exactly what CSS is being applied?

It looks like the problem is occurring in your styling for the lang-dropbtn class. You specified a padding of 16px, which is causing the aforementioned background issue. To fix this, there are two routes.

You can remove the padding entirely, as shown in the code snippet at the end of the answer.
You can remove the background only by using background: none.



document.querySelector('.lang-dropbtn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('.lang-dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show');
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop propagation to prevent window click handler from closing the dropdown immediately
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.closest('.language-dropdown')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("lang-dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      dropdowns[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
.language-dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2000;
  /* Ensuring it is above other content */
}

.lang-dropbtn {
  padding: 0; /* changed from 16px to 0 to remove background */
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Rounded button */
}

.lang-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  /* Adjusted for spacing */
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Padding around flags */
}

.lang-dropdown-content .lang-a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* Vertical spacing between flags */
}

.lang-dropdown-content .lang-a .lang-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Make images circular */
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  /* Center align images */
}

.language-dropdown:hover .lang-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  /* Show dropdown on hover */
}
<div class="language-dropdown">
  <button class="lang-dropbtn">
    <img class="lang-img" src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/171f64-06f6-0f4b-8e88-7b2cded67131_british_flag.png" alt="British" style="width:40px;height:auto;">
  </button>
  <div class="lang-dropdown-content">
    <!-- <a class="lang-a" href="/en"><img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/171f64-06f6-0f4b-8e88-7b2cded67131_british_flag.png" alt="British"></a> -->
    <a class="lang-a" href="/cn"><img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/e0bb117-b0a2-40b-0145-11ae625b76ca_chinese_flag.png" alt="Chinese"></a>
    <a class="lang-a" href="/ar"><img src="https://kajabi-storefronts-production.kajabi-cdn.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/file-uploads/themes/2156294001/settings_images/7c2c8b5-343-6aa2-240-dd2613be2af8_saudi_flag.png" alt="Arabic"></a>
  </div>
</div>



